# How to ensure correct ordering when using a for loop in truffle test

Tags: truffle, javascript, testrpc, testing

I am using truffle (javascript) to test my solidity contracts and want to automatically run my contract functions a large number of times. I can't figure out how to make a for loop work with promises however as I need it to wait until the whole loop is finished to start again. I'm currently just using a regular for loop with the promises chained up within it. I have included below my roughly anonymised code.

Thanks

```
for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    //create parameters for function
    runFunc(param1 ,param2);
}

function runFunc(param1, param2) {
    contract.func1.call(param1).then(function(return1) {
        var var1 = = web3.toAscii(account1hash.valueOf());
        contract.func2(param2, var1).then(function() {
            contract.func3(param1, param2);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this...

NB: accounts is a global variable with test wallets passed in to the test by truffle.
should.be.fulfilled is using the chai-as-promised NPM module - checks for errors

```
  it('Checks we are keeping track of total enlisted', async function() {
    for (var i=0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
      await this.WhitelistV2.enlist(accounts[i], {from: _}).should.be.fulfilled;  
      total +=1;
    }
    total.should.be.equal(accounts.length);
  });
```